# F1 measure vs accuarcy for comparing two models

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

As I understand accuracy is not good measure for comparing the performance of two models when data is unbalanced and F1 measure is better than it in that case, so, I am trying to come up with example for two models where model A is better than model B but accuracy of B greater than accuracy of A while F1 for A is greater than F1 of B.
is there such case? if not please tell me why and if yes please give me example.

Comment: Another metric you should have a look is the balanced accuracy. You can find it [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use any imbalanced dataset from UCI repository or Kaggle. One good dataset for this would be credit card fraud dataset or any cancer dataset which are available on both repositories. These datasets will give you good accuracy of 99.99% and bad F1 score when trained without any processing to handle the imbalance between classes.

[Credit card dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud)

[Cancer Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+(Diagnostic))

Comment: is it possible for model A to have greater accuracy than model B while having less F1 score than model B? soory for this question but I am still a beginner

Comment: Yes this will happen for sure if model A is trained on imbalanced data and model B is trained by processing data into balanced set.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please provide a bit more info about the background story?
>   What kind of models are you comparing, what's the data set like?

Indeed, comparing accuracies may not be enough. I wrote a [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/comparing-machine-learning-models-statistical-vs-practical-significance-de345c38b42a) some time ago about ML Model Comparison, you may wanna check it out.

Comment: @MadMike the link should work now. My apologies! :)